# Remove \u character with Regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text from IRC:

```
:art!art@irc.org private #timing :\u000314CODEERROR:\u0003 [\u000304X012\u0003] Server time is different than UTC
```

I tried to remove stuff `\u000314` and so on.

I tried

```
var test = Regex.Replace(text, @"\\u0{3}3\d{0,2}", string.Empty);
```

not working means does not remove characters.

I tried too:

```
var test = Regex.Replace(text, @"\u0{3}3\d{0,2}", string.Empty);
```

Here I receivce an exception of insufficient hexadecimal digits.

See fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7H5G95

Comment: The first regular expression works fine. Can you please provide you code?

Comment: You're calling `Regex.Replace` but not doing anything with the result. Strings are immutable - no method will change their content; instead any method with a name like "replace" will return a new string with the different content.

Comment: What @Jon Means, use: text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\\u0{3}3\d{0,2}", string.Empty);

Comment: I updated question

Comment: The code works fine: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/a52a799b17d83a99db3725a0a7a7443b My *guess* is that you don't actually have that text, but that's what you're seeing in the debugger, and that actually you have text that includes U+0003.

Comment: That fiddle fails due to the regular expression being invalid - it's your second version. Add the extra backslash though (as per your first version) and it's fine.

Comment: It's from debugger, yes, Inside it is a ``  and it is interpreted as \u0003 etc

Comment: Is `text.Replace("\u0003", string.Empty)` what you need?

Comment: It's worth being really careful when asking questions in future that you represent the data correctly - in this case you *don't* have the text that your question talks about, which has led us on a bit of a wild goose chase. One way of avoiding this is to provide a [mcve] from the start - that way we're at least all working with the same information. (It may still be incorrect, but there won't be any confusion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem you have. The following code (with first regex) works:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = @":art!art@irc.org private #timing :\u000314CODEERROR:\u0003 [\u000304X012\u0003] Server time is different than UTC";
        var res = Regex.Replace(text, @"\\u0{3}3\d{0,2}", string.Empty);
        System.Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
:art!art@irc.org private #timing :CODEERROR: [X012] Server time is different than UTC
```